Firebase Kotlin SDK callbacks
I'm building a new Compose Multiplatform project and I want to add in some Firestore functionality.
I added the Firebase Kotlin SDK: https://github.com/GitLiveApp/firebase-kotlin-sdk
# build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
    alias(libs.plugins.googleServices)
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "2.0.0-RC3"
}
kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
        }
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-firestore:1.12.0")
            implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-common:1.12.0")
        }
    }
}

But I can't add any callback on my Firestore calls, like addSnapshotListener or addOnSuccessListener I get: Unresolved reference: addSnapshotListener
suspend fun getDocument(id: String) {
    val db = Firebase.firestore
    try {
        val result = db.collection("session").document(id).get().addSnapshotListener { }
    } catch (e: Exception) {

    }
}

I would like to listen to changes in the data from the FireStore and update the UI when it happens.

The DocumentReference#get() method returns an object of type Task<DocumentSnapshot!>, so there is no way you can call addSnapshotListener on such an object. If you want to listen for real-time updates of a specific document then you have to call addSnapshotListener directly on the DocumentReference object like this:
suspend fun getDocument(id: String) {
    val db = Firebase.firestore
    try {
        val result = db.collection("session").document(id).addSnapshotListener{ }
    } catch (e: Exception) {

    }
}

See, I have removed the get() call. So this is possible because the addSnapshotListener() method belongs to the DocumentReference class and not to the Task<DocumentSnapshot!> class.

I found this discussion on the github repo and it looks like this is working for my use case. https://github.com/GitLiveApp/firebase-kotlin-sdk/discussions/115 Im not using the official Firebase sdk because it does not support Compose Multiplatform yet.
